# Sub web component in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-webui

Is it possible to make sub web components in `Dart` ?

Say, for example, I have a `x-chatwindow` custom element and I would like it to have an `x-textarea` and `x-textinput` sub component.

A fictional implementation would be :

```dart
<x-chatwindow>
    <x-textarea/>
    <x-textinput/>
</x-chatwindow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific problem you are facing?

You can use the [`<content></content>`](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-web-components/#composition) inside your `ChatWindowComponent` template:

```html
<element name="x-chat-window" constructor="ChatWindowComponent" extends="div">
  <template>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</element>
```

Then the page where you use them:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="components" href="components/chat_window.html" />
    <link rel="components" href="components/text_area.html" />
    <link rel="components" href="components/text_input.html" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-chat-window>
      <x-text-area></x-text-area>
      <x-text-input></x-text-input>
    </x-chat-window>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No particular problem so far. I just saw this in a Google IO talk and didn't know to do it. I guess I'm looking to have the parent component somehow influence the properties of the sub components. Don't know if that is possible yet but this is a start. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answer tested on "Dart M3", "Dart Editor build 20259" and "web_ui 0.4.2 + 5"

In addition to Kai Sellgren's answer, WebComponents can be hidden inside other WebComponents. In your case inside "xchatwindow.html", textarea and text input could be linked as;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="components" href="components/xtextarea.html">
  <link rel="components" href="components/xtextinput.html">
</head>
<body>
  <element name="x-chat-window" constructor="FormComponent" extends="div">

...
```